# Unable to redirect HTTPS to HTTP via NGINX

Tags: nginx, https, http, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having a very hard time doing a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP. This is giving me the last few days some headache because I can't figure it out :|

**situation**

I have a website and a VPS server. The website is hosted on a separate web hosting. On the VPS server, I have an API that is only reachable via HTTP. For example, a curl API call can look like this `curl http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4000/foo/bar`

The VPS has the NGINX installed with the following NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen <website-domain-ip>:443;
    server_name localhost <website-domain> www.<website-domain>;
    ssl_certificate     /root/certificates/<website-domain>/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/certificates/<website-domain>/private.key;

    location ~ / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    }
 }

# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name <website-domain> www.<website-domain>;
#    return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri;
# }
```

However, when I try the API I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
The full error

```
GET https://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4000/foo/bar net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**What have you tried?**

I have tried multiple configurations mainly to change the `listen` to only `443` or adding `ssl`. I think that the problem is here (there will probably be more problems, but the first problem is here I think).
The access.log and error.log is empty which should mean there is no connection whatsoever and the `listen` property is not configured correctly.

I do have control over the ssl certificates and I have the cert, ca_bundle, and private key.

Who can help me out?

**UPDATE**

full output of curl -IL https://example.com/foo/bar
`curl: (35) error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number`

On the VPS `lsof -i` gives the following running processes

```
systemd-n   690 systemd-network   15u  IPv4 853475      0t0  UDP ip185-132-47-xxx.pbiaas.com:bootpc 
systemd-r   692 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  24956      0t0  UDP localhost:domain 
systemd-r   692 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  24957      0t0  TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)
sshd        744            root    3u  IPv4  24330      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd        744            root    4u  IPv6  24332      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
postgres    782        postgres    5u  IPv6  31871      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres    782        postgres    6u  IPv4  31872      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres    782        postgres    8u  IPv6  31877      0t0  UDP localhost:60421->localhost:60421 
postgres    788        postgres    8u  IPv6  31877      0t0  UDP localhost:60421->localhost:60421 
postgres    789        postgres    8u  IPv6  31877      0t0  UDP localhost:60421->localhost:60421 
postgres    790        postgres    8u  IPv6  31877      0t0  UDP localhost:60421->localhost:60421 
postgres    791        postgres    8u  IPv6  31877      0t0  UDP localhost:60421->localhost:60421 
postgres    792        postgres    8u  IPv6  31877      0t0  UDP localhost:60421->localhost:60421 
postgres    793        postgres    8u  IPv6  31877      0t0  UDP localhost:60421->localhost:60421 
nginx     35874            root    6u  IPv4 647926      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     35874            root    7u  IPv4 647927      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     35875        www-data    6u  IPv4 647926      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     35875        www-data    7u  IPv4 647927      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     35876        www-data    6u  IPv4 647926      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     35876        www-data    7u  IPv4 647927      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     35877        www-data    6u  IPv4 647926      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     35877        www-data    7u  IPv4 647927      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     35878        www-data    6u  IPv4 647926      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     35878        www-data    7u  IPv4 647927      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     35879        www-data    6u  IPv4 647926      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     35879        www-data    7u  IPv4 647927      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     35880        www-data    6u  IPv4 647926      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     35880        www-data    7u  IPv4 647927      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
sshd      47034            root    4u  IPv4 854019      0t0  TCP ip185-132-47-xxx.pbiaas.com:ssh->148-216-099-087.dynamic.<internet-provider>.<country-code>:55102 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      47257            root    4u  IPv4 853604      0t0  TCP ip185-132-47-xxx.pbiaas.com:ssh->119.96.159.237:54986 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: With the proxy, your API is at `https://example.com/foo/bar` (on the default HTTPS port `443`). Do not try to redirect anything.

Comment: What is the response to `curl -I https://example.com/foo/bar`?

Comment: @RichardSmith curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 4000 after 35 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Comment: Please edit the full output of `curl -IL https://example.com/foo/bar` into your question.

Comment: Oh, and the redirect in your HTTP server block creates an endless loop. It should redirect to `https`. But that shouldn't affect the problem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider the answer is updated, I have commented out the http server block for clearity. Looks like the SSL certificate is wrong?

Comment: Well, either you have another server block that listens on port 443 with HTTP or your server or your client is so heavily outdated that the SSL procol mismatches. But that raises the question why you got a proper answer for your request before.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider my nginx version is: `nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)` and my chrome browser is up to date. I have tried firefox and that gave me different error then chrome `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4000/foo/bar. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

Comment: Well, without seeing all responses from a single request we can only guess. Either you have another server block active that is not shown or the redirect to the port :4000 comes from your backend server. The problem is not the nginx config you are showing.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider is probably a stupid question, but what do you mean with all responses? When using the `curl IL` and the browser output that's all I get

Comment: Run `curl -IL` on a well known website, for example google.com. Do this with HTTP (NOT HTTPS). You'll see a lot of HTTP header lines, including redirects to HTTPS. That is the kind of output that shows helpful diagnostic information. This is what we need for requests to your domain. We could look this up ourselves if you weren't obfuscating your config. I can understand if you don't want to share this information, but then you will have to type commands you are being told. Alternatively, if curl doesn't work, `wget -S --spider` shows the same helpful information.

Comment: Looks like there is more wrong with my server because I don't get that much output HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2023 09:13:49 GMT
Server: Kestrel
X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 1s
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 4
X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 2023-09-19T09:13:50.9289443Z

Comment: So, there is another webserver involved you haven't disclosed yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148624/discussion-between-j-p-and-gerald-schneider).